# Incrementing with Methods in Java & (Added) Array Processing

Tags: java

I have a question about Java:

```
public class Tester {

  private int[] testArray = {3, 4, 5};

  public void increment(int n) {

       n++;
  }
  public void firstTestMethod() {
       for(int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
            increment(testArray[i]);
            System.out.print(testArray[i] + " ");
       }
  } 
}
```

The output produced when invoking `firstTestMethod` for a `Tester` object is 3 4 5. Could someone please help explain why? Thank you!

---

Hi all,

Could anyone take a look at this other problem? The correct answer is C, but I just don't understand! The link to the picture is below.

Thanks in advance!

[Answer is C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r9E7.jpg)

Comment: Your int is passed by value.

Comment: `i` looks undefined?

Comment: For primitive arguments (int, long, etc.), the pass by value is the actual value of the primitive. So a copy is created and incremented there. value in the testArray[ ] remains the same.

Comment: Thanks everyone!